# Android Child Views inside FrameLayout are Clickable ,How to disable the click of frameLayout child?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

when i click the textview its opens the list item popup activity but i set textview `android:clickable="false"` is not working so how to i disable the click of FrameLayout Child views

```
<FrameLayout        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:orientation="vertical">    

    <ListView        
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fadingEdge="none"/>   

    <LinearLayout        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Text"/>

    </LinearLayout> 

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where you write the click for TextView ?

Comment: i not write any click to textview but when i click textview the click event goes to listview i dont no why this happens

Answer (score 1):

As you want `TextView` to scroll with ListView as last time the best way is to add that View as *footer of the ListView*

```
TextView mFooterTextView = new TextView(mContext);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

and your XML will be

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fadingEdge="none"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `textview its opens the list item popup activity`  where you had written this code. show your java file.

Comment: popup activity will open only on List item setOnclickListener

Comment: listview foreground as textview that is the problem

Comment: @sarath is it compulsory to use FrameLayout ?

Comment: yes on listview scroll down and up i will need show and hide the textview on framelayout

Comment: mean text will also scroll with listview as last item of the listview ?

Comment: on every time listview scroll down and up i will need show and hide the textview. so View as footer of the ListView is not suitable